# Django Admin Recent Actions in a react Js website

Tags: python, django, logging, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I want to know if I can use the logs that are displayed on Django Admin in a custom React Js Admin Panel. I have a requirement which is to show all recent changes done by any user. Django admin already has that Recent Actions widget. How can I use that data and serialize it in some API/View

I tried using django-simple-history but it shows specific history for a specific object. I want a complete generic log list

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That data in the admin is based on the `LogEntry` model from `django.contrib.admin`: [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#logentry-objects)

The 'recent actions' list in the admin is generated when the [template for the index](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html) page of the admin calls the `get_admin_log` template tag. That tag creates a template node that sets a context variable to the recent LogEntry objects of the user. [See here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/log.py). The index template then renders the LogEntry objects from that variable.

So basically, you just need to add a view that queries the LogEntry model for the most recent actions of the current user and then returns the serialized queryset.